# Rendering Partial view as a string inside SignalR Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1, asp.net-core-signalr

I am trying to dynamically load partial view contents in one of my views via a SignalR Hub to update client side data. For this I have to render the Partial view as a string in the SignalR Hub and send this string to the client side. I know how to render a partial view as a string inside a controller, but how would I do this outside of a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to dynamically load partial view contents in one of my views via a SignalR Hub to update client side data. For this I have to render the Partial view as a string in the SignalR Hub and send this string to the client side.

If you'd like to render your view/partial view as a html string within your hub method, you can refer to [this blog with example that demonstrates how to render a Partial View to string](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/render-partial-to-string).

And I did a test with the example code `RazorPartialToStringRenderer` in my SignalR app, which work well for me.

```
private readonly IRazorPartialToStringRenderer _renderer;
public ChatHub(IRazorPartialToStringRenderer renderer)
{
    _renderer = renderer;
}
public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
{

    var view_result_mes = await _renderer.RenderPartialToStringAsync<string>("_SayHelloPartialView", null);

    //...
```

*Code referenced from above blog*

```
public interface IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model);
}

public class RazorPartialToStringRenderer : IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public RazorPartialToStringRenderer(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public async Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();
        var partial = FindView(actionContext, partialName);
        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                partial,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            await partial.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
    private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string partialName)
    {
        var getPartialResult = _viewEngine.GetView(null, partialName, false);
        if (getPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return getPartialResult.View;
        }
        var findPartialResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, partialName, false);
        if (findPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return findPartialResult.View;
        }
        var searchedLocations = getPartialResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findPartialResult.SearchedLocations);
        var errorMessage = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            new[] { $"Unable to find partial '{partialName}'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations)); ;
        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
    }
    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = _serviceProvider
        };
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. It is working in my SignalR Hub.

Comment: It is working for most of my views, but some razor codes raise an error. I have this line of code in one of my cshtml files: @Html.ActionLink(@Strings.ButtonConfigure, "Edit", "EBS", new { id = Ebs.CurrentMacAddress.ToHex48String() }), which references a controller EBS and action Edit. The partial view to string renderer raises this error: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.". I saw people at this blog have a similar issue: https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/.

Comment: The above described exception is easily bypassable by rewriting it as <a href="/Controller/Action/"...> so it isn't really a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

SignalR gives us the oppotunity to get rid of Razor Pages and use Plain Javascript to render you Html Async.
So In case you want to render a template of html just write a template of function which returns the html code you want

```
function messageMeTemplate(user, message) {
return `
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end ms-auto">
        <p class="p-3 bg-primary shadow-1-strong text-white rounded-3" style="max-width: 533px">
            ${message}
            <small class="float-end mt-4">${user}</small>
        </p>
        <img src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/new/avatars/1.jpg" class="rounded-circle ms-2" style="width: 30px; height: 30px" alt="" />
    </div>
`;
}
```

Also you can write in a section with script in razor page of this command to load you the partial view in a div you want to take it for Javascript.

```
$('#AREA_PARTIAL_VIEW').load('@Url.Action("Insert_Partial_View","Customers")');
```

Both of the examples you need a template to render it.
I would like to mention that we talk about SignalR Core.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with, thanks to Fei Han.

RazorPartialToStringRenderer class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewEngines;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public interface IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model);
}

public class RazorPartialToStringRenderer : IRazorPartialToStringRenderer
{
    private IRazorViewEngine _viewEngine;
    private ITempDataProvider _tempDataProvider;
    private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public RazorPartialToStringRenderer(
        IRazorViewEngine viewEngine,
        ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        _viewEngine = viewEngine;
        _tempDataProvider = tempDataProvider;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }
    public async Task<string> RenderPartialToStringAsync<TModel>(string partialName, TModel model)
    {
        var actionContext = GetActionContext();
        var partial = FindView(actionContext, partialName);
        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(
                actionContext,
                partial,
                new ViewDataDictionary<TModel>(
                    metadataProvider: new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(),
                    modelState: new ModelStateDictionary())
                {
                    Model = model
                },
                new TempDataDictionary(
                    actionContext.HttpContext,
                    _tempDataProvider),
                output,
                new HtmlHelperOptions()
            );
            await partial.RenderAsync(viewContext);
            return output.ToString();
        }
    }
    private IView FindView(ActionContext actionContext, string partialName)
    {
        var getPartialResult = _viewEngine.GetView(null, partialName, false);
        if (getPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return getPartialResult.View;
        }
        var findPartialResult = _viewEngine.FindView(actionContext, partialName, false);
        if (findPartialResult.Success)
        {
            return findPartialResult.View;
        }
        var searchedLocations = getPartialResult.SearchedLocations.Concat(findPartialResult.SearchedLocations);
        var errorMessage = string.Join(
            Environment.NewLine,
            new[] { $"Unable to find partial '{partialName}'. The following locations were searched:" }.Concat(searchedLocations));
        throw new InvalidOperationException(errorMessage);
    }
    private ActionContext GetActionContext()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext
        {
            RequestServices = _serviceProvider
        };
        return new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new ActionDescriptor());
    }
}
```

Hub and HubMethods classes:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace WebApplication
{
    public class EBSHubMethods
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<EBSHub> _hubContext;
        private readonly IServiceScopeFactory _serviceScopeFactory;
        private readonly Timer timer = null;

        public EBSHubMethods(IHubContext<EBSHub> hubContext, IServiceScopeFactory serviceScopeFactory)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            _serviceScopeFactory = serviceScopeFactory;

            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 10000;
            timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
            timer.Start();
        }

        private async Task<string> GetEBSListViewAsString()
        {
            using (var scope = _serviceScopeFactory.CreateScope())
            {
                var _renderer = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRazorPartialToStringRenderer>();
                string viewAsString = await _renderer.RenderPartialToStringAsync("~/Views/EBS/_EBSPartial.cshtml", BaseStations);
                return viewAsString;
            }
        }

        private async void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateEBSList", await GetEBSListViewAsString());            
        }

        public async void SendEBSList(string connectionId)
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("UpdateEBSList", await GetEBSListViewAsString());
        }
    }

    public class EBSHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly EBSHubMethods _EBSHubMethods = null;

        public EBSHub(EBSHubMethods EBSHubMethods)
        {
            _EBSHubMethods = EBSHubMethods;            
        }

        public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            _EBSHubMethods.SendEBSList(Context.ConnectionId);
            await base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }

        public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }
    }
}
```

And in the Startup.cs file we register the Hub, and add the EBSHubMethods as a singleton service and the RazorPartialToStringRenderer as a transient service:

```
services.AddSingleton<EBSHubMethods>();
services.AddTransient<IRazorPartialToStringRenderer, RazorPartialToStringRenderer>();
```